# how can I extract content from an specific text in this excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I got this text

```
"You received a new message from your online store's contact form.

Email:
name@gmail.com

Body:
Please notify me when "Product" becomes available."
```

How can i extract the content in that PRODUCT? assuming that it can vary a lot in length... example it might be product x or product xxxxxx.

I have tried with

```
=MID(A2,FIND("when",A2)+5,FIND("available.",A2)-1)
```

not working just showing the whole after "when", not the exactly product.

Thank you very much in advance
Javier

Comment: Is the content actually demarcated through quotation marks?

Comment: Give this a shot `=MID(A2,FIND("""",A2) + 1, FIND(""" becomes",A2) - FIND("""",A2) - 1)`. That means you start where you find the first `"`. You get # of characters from that point to where you find `" becomes`

Comment: hey!! this works as expected! thank you a million man!

Comment: @JavierRiosFernández I'll add that as an answer. When you get a chance, you can click on the check box beside the answer to give closure to your question.

Comment: @JavierRiosFernández you have a couple of answers. If you feel comfortable, can you put closure to your question by marking one of the answers as accepted? You can do so by clicking on the check mark by the answer of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Ah yes, I've had this trouble many times. The issue is intuitively you would expect the mid formula to be =MID(text, start position, **end position**) but actually it's =MID(text, start position, **number of characters**)

So you can calcualte the number of characters by subtracting the end position from the length:
`=MID(A2,FIND("when",A2)+5, LEN(A2)-FIND("available.",A2)-1 )`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("""",A2) + 1, FIND(""" becomes",A2) - FIND("""",A2) - 1)
```

Explanation:

- `FIND("""",A2)` will find the position of first double-quote
- `FIND(""" becomes",A2)` finds the position where `" becomes` is found
- We take the difference of those two positions, do a bit of math and extract what you need